# What distribution is this?

Tags: statistics, distribution

I am trying to find the distribution of this histogram: [Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqNtF.png)

I tried fitting normal, log-normal, gamma, and Weibull using fitdist() in R, and this is the result: [Fits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2t2t.png)

Log-normal looks like the best fit among the others and has the lowest AIC and BIC. Would you say then it is the best fit? It looks very off especially the first peak. What other distributions would you test?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is statistics / probability modeling. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of the site to see what kinds of questions are appropriate here

Comment: Looks like a mixture distribution, with three components (bumps). You could use what you know about the problem domain to determine what the distribution for each component should be. A web search for "mixture distribution" will find some resources. For the record, this question is off topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.